# Asp.net file download for Android application chooser

Tags: android, asp.net, download, mobile-website

I'm trying to get my file download to work as if it was a direct link to the file path on the server.

Currently I'm performing file downloads similar to this: http://www.devtoolshed.com/aspnet-download-file-web-browser

I've seen that if you have a link to a direct file like so:

```
<a href="/path/to/file/myfile.pdf> Download </a>
```

This will cause the Android browser to show an application chooser window so to open the PDF in the appropriate application.

I'm currently having something like this:

```
<a href="Default.aspx?file=myfile.pdf"> Download </a>
```

This causes the browser to immediately download the file but it doesn't show the application chooser afterwards.

How do I get this method to perform as if it was a direct link on android(4.4.2) stock browser.

**EDIT**: (VB.NET)

```
        httpContext.Response.Clear()
        httpContext.Response.ClearHeaders()
        httpContext.Response.ClearContent()
        httpContext.Response.ContentType = mimetype //In this case it is "application/pdf" 

        httpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(filepath).Length)
        httpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=""" & filename & """")

        httpContext.Response.Flush()
        httpContext.Response.WriteFile(filepath)

        httpContext.Response.Flush()
        httpContext.Response.End()
```

I've tried both (inline and attachment) for the content-disposition. makes not difference in this case. I'll look into converting this to ".ashx" but I don't this will will have an affect on the response output stream.

Also the file name isn't being downloaded correctly either.

Comment: Show your code for the Default.aspx where it sends the file to the client. Probably it's in your Page_Load method. By the way, if you need to have functionality for download files, it's probably better to put them in a Generic Handler (.ashx) instead of a Page (.aspx). That's because downloading a file doesn't typically require a UI and you don't need all that overhead.

Comment: my guess is that you are not returning the correct Mime Type for your pdf. The mime type should be application/x-pdf. Also what @mason says is true. You should probably go the ashx way

Comment: I've added the code-behind to the post.